# How to create a .deb file just for copying certain icons and one javascript file to particular locations?

Tags: packaging, deb

Okay,So I have wasted my whole day and still unable to figure out how to do that the easy way.I have been to the debian land and ubuntu packaging land.I have read about equivs and various other ways but still no progress.Those are all bulky pieces of texts.Is creating a .deb to do such a small/easy thing is that much difficult in Ubuntu/debian?

Comment: why not create a simple bash script?

Comment: Actually,I want to distribute my work as a package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a GUI software instead, like [Deb-creator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/deb-creator), here are some screenshots of the software:

<sup>Contents of output window</sup>
[image]

<sup>Deb-Creators user interface outlining key features</sup>
[image]