# Creating a .deb that just places/updates config files?

Tags: package-management, deb, configuration-management

I was surprised to not find more people asking this question, but so far I've only found [one from a couple of years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205480/how-to-create-a-deb-file-just-for-copying-certain-icons-and-one-javascript-file), with not much in the way of responses.

First, some background on what I'm actually trying to accomplish here: I am working on a custom spin of Edubuntu designed for use by educational nonprofits in low/no-bandwidth locations. The server would need to come pre-configured in some specific ways, and I need a reliable way to provide updates to those configurations without having direct access to the systems. Thus, a .deb repository that can be put on a USB drive if necessary seems like a reasonable solution.

It looks like the *packagename*.install file wants you to specify every file and dir that you want to include in your package individually. For a package that just places or updates files on a system, this seems like overkill (and quite tedious if you have a lot of files/dirs), as opposed to having something like this your build dir:

```
fs/
 |-etc/
    |-apache2/
         |- conf.d/
               |- some_custom_settings.conf
 |-var/
    |-www/
         |-html/
            |- some_custom_page.html

AND SO ON
```

and then having the "build" process basically just be `rsync -a fs/ /`

...but then, that also seems a bit hacky, which makes me wonder if I'm either missing something or just using the wrong tool for the job.

Of course, I could just suck it up and use the more tedious *packagename*.install approach to make .debs, or maybe I should look into something like Puppet instead, assuming there's a way to push updates to disconnected systems in that scenario. Or maybe just a git repo?

Basically, I'd welcome any suggestions, whether via .debs or something else.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can answer!

Comment: Hmm... potentially relevant: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/man/apply.html

Answer (score 0):

Effing Package Management https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm is one of my favorite tools for creating packages.

Create the directory tree you want and use [https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/Source:-dir](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/Source%3a-dir)

Comment: Wow, that was remarkably, refreshingly easy! I'm still open to someone making the case that I should be using Puppet or somesuch for this, but I've already got fpm up and running in a way that makes a .deb-based solution practically trivial. Thanks!

Comment: by the way, if you ever need a config management tool, I would recommend ansible http://docs.ansible.com. simple and powerful.